# How to parse title from the website with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to receive the title, but my function doesn't work.
`GetHTTPResponse` works well and I receive HTML code
But `GetTitle` doesn't output any data.

```
Function GetHTTPResponse(ByVal sURL As String) As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    With oXMLHTTP
        .Open "GET", sURL, False
        .send
        GetHTTPResponse = .responseText
    End With
    Set oXMLHTTP = Nothing
End Function

Function GetTitle()
Data = GetHTTPResponse("https://www.google.com/")
findTag = "<title>"
Search = InStr(1, Data, findTag)
End Function
```

I run in the immediate window
`? GetTitle ()`
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BmM8.png

How can I solve it?

Comment: (1) Put Option Explicit at the top of the module (2) Declare (Dim) all variables. (3) Get rid of "On Error Resume Next". (4) Step through the code and examine the value of each variable. That should get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the `responseText` as `innerHTML` to a `HTMLfile` object and working with the DOM (Document Object Model). With the DOM method `getElementsByTagName()` you can get the title than.
[Element.getElementsByTagName() on MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)

```
Sub GetHTTPResponse()
  
  Const url As String = "https://www.google.com/"
  Dim doc As Object
  
  Set doc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
  
  With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    .Open "GET", url, False
    .send
    If .Status = 200 Then
      doc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
      MsgBox doc.getElementsByTagName("title")(0).innerText
    Else
      MsgBox "Page not loaded. HTTP status: " & .Status
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`GetTitle` doesn't return any value (missing `GetTitle = ...`)